# Creating new users via terminal does not assign correct permissions?

Tags: debian, useradd, accounts

I am creating a new user for a Linux Debian distribution.

I did use the command to create a new user via terminal, while I was logged in as root; tehn assigned the user to the sudo group, so I can install and run commands as superuser when needed (without swap with su).

Is there a sequence of commands to perform, to create a user, create the home folder, assign it to sudo group and such?

This is the sequence of commands that I performed:

```
<login as root>
useradd myuser
passwd myuser
adduser myuser sudo
usermod myuser -s /bin/bash
<logout and login as myuser>
```

At this point, I had no home folder set up; created one via sudo but obviously it has Root as owner, so I can't do anything inside it.

I had to use chown to change the home permission, although this doesn't seems right.

What else do I need to do, to have a proper user created?

Comment: You're using `adduser` anyway. Why not just run `adduser myuser`, and skip the `passwd` and `usermod` commands?

Comment: Right, I could set the password in the adduser command; although neither the standard console nor the group parameter were accepted, so I ended up calling each command separately. Maybe I was doing something wrong

Comment: What do you mean? `adduser` has a `--shell  <SHELL>` option, but `/bin/bash` would be the default. It doesn't have an option for extra groups, unlike `useradd`, yes.

Comment: I did use the -s option while using useradd, to use bash instead of sh, and it was failing. I was not aware of adduser being a replacement for useradd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) says, you should just use `adduser`:

```
adduser myuser
```

will prompt for `myuser`'s GECOS information and password, and create `myuser`'s home directory with the appropriate permissions. The default shell should be `/bin/bash`. `adduser` will also populate the new home directory with the contents of `/etc/skel` (default shell initialisation scripts etc.).

All that's needed then is to add `myuser` to the `sudo` group, as you're doing already, so the whole sequence becomes

```
adduser myuser
adduser myuser sudo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot; I was not aware that adduser can be used as whole replacedment for useradd